# Maven: set code variable in properties

Tags: java, maven, archetypes

Is it possible to define custom values when a project is generated from an archetype? How could this be done?

For example if i wanted to allow a developer to enter a string value that would be hardcoded into the the source of the application, such as a url string.

Answer (score 2):

Maven profile is just for you.

http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino/portofino3/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add properties in the POM file, in a `<properties>...</properties>` block. You can then use these properties later on in the POM file, such as in configuring plugins.

Comment: Would it be possible to set something in a code file?

e.g.
String myCoolUrl =  ${inserturlhere}

myconnection.load(myCoolUrl)

Answer (score 1):

In the archetype-descriptor you can specify requiredProperties the user has to provide. You can use these properties later in the code or in the POM files.